# Display buffer and otput tfpdf file

Tags: php, output, fpdf, output-buffering

below VERY simplified piece of code showing the situation that I have.

```
if($pdf_success) {
    echo 'Success! Your download is starting';
    
    ob_end_clean()
    
    $pdf->Output('D', 'filename.pdf');

} else {
    echo 'Failure! Try again with different parameters.';
}
```

and here is the problem:

if I don't `use ob_end_clean()` pdf download fails with the message:

```
Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at .....
```

If I use it, pdf downloads/displays correctly, but the message does not show...

Using first `ob_end_flush()` shows the message but stops the download with the same message, and using `ob_end_clean()` does not help but results with the message:

```
PHP Notice:  ob_end_clean(): failed to delete buffer. No buffer to delete in ....
```

How to both display a message and after that start successfully the download???

Thanks.

Comment: You can't send both a PDF and something else in a single HTTP request.

Comment: So it should display the message and then open new link to start pdf download?